# Engine seize after water pump repair

Tags: skoda

Coolant leakage was detected but repaired after 10 days. Coolant level was monitored during this period.
After 1 month of repair the engine seized. Reason given was engine oil and coolant mixed .
Can someone pl tell if ihe damge is considered caused during those 10 days of non repair

Comment: Waterpump repair should be unrelated to oil/coolant mix. Probably a blown head-gasket? If regularly checked, engine-oil should have given clues of water in it. Normally this does not happen over night.

Comment: I'd go with Daniel's theory here.

Comment: It is possible that while the pump was leaking, the coolant got low enough for the engine to overheat. This could have resulted in a blown head gasket or worse. Coolant contaminating the oil will shorten engine life.

Comment: "I don't see how we can possibly know. Was the oil replaced at the time of repair? – Chenmunka yesterday"                                                                            3 months before this there was indication for low engine oil and it was replaced.   Do the dots connect

Comment: If the fuel pump was replaced and seize happens after 1 month of this repair then who is responsible.